# "Unfurtunately, Stealth has stopped" FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Tags: java, android

Independente da alteração que eu faça, continuo sem nenhuma solução para esse problema. O android emulator continua aparecendo a msg "Unfurtunately, Stealth has stopped". Sendo que na Main não apresenta nenhum erro, mas na execução da FATAL EXCEPTION: main. Todas a variavas estão declaradas corretamente. Peço por gentileza me deem uma luz perante isso.
Abaixo tenho a xml e o .java.

```
package com.example.stealth2017;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
//import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
//import android.view.Menu;
//import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Stealth2017MainActivity extends Activity {

    EditText editTextComprimento;
    EditText editTextLargura;
    EditText editTextAltura;

    TextView TextFieldComprimento;
    TextView TextFieldRLargura;
    TextView TextFieldRAltura;

    Button buttonVerificarMedidas;
    Button buttonCalculaAV;
    EditText editTextArea;
    EditText editTextVolume;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_stealth2017_main);

        final AlertDialog.Builder alerta = new AlertDialog.Builder(Stealth2017MainActivity.this);

        editTextComprimento = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextComprimento);
        editTextLargura = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextLargura);
        editTextAltura = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextAltura);
        editTextArea = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextArea);
        editTextVolume = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextVolume);

        buttonCalculaAV = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonCalculaAV);
        buttonVerificarMedidas = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonVerificarMedidas);

        TextFieldComprimento = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextFieldComprimento);
        TextFieldRLargura = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextFieldLargura);
        TextFieldRAltura = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextFieldAltura);


        buttonVerificarMedidas.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                    double Altura, Comprimento, Largura;

                    Altura = Double.parseDouble(editTextAltura.getText().toString());
                    Comprimento = Double.parseDouble(editTextComprimento.getText().toString());
                    Largura = Double.parseDouble(editTextLargura.getText().toString());


                    if (Comprimento >= 3.0) {
                        editTextComprimento.setText(String.valueOf(Comprimento));
                    } else {
                        alerta.setTitle("Atenção");
                        alerta.setMessage("Comprimento mínimo 3 metros !");
                        alerta.setNeutralButton("OK", null);
                        alerta.show();
                        editTextComprimento.setText("");
                    }


                    if (Altura >= 3.5) {
                        editTextAltura.setText(String.valueOf(Altura));
                    } else {
                        alerta.setTitle("Atenção");
                        alerta.setMessage("Altura mínima 3.5 metros !");
                        alerta.setNeutralButton("OK", null);
                        alerta.show();
                        editTextAltura.setText("");
                    }


                    if (Largura >= 3.0) {
                        editTextLargura.setText(String.valueOf(Largura));
                    } else {
                        alerta.setTitle("Atenção");
                        alerta.setMessage("Largura mínima 3 metros !");
                        alerta.setNeutralButton("OK", null);
                        alerta.show();
                        editTextLargura.setText("");
                    }
                    buttonCalculaAV.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View arg0) {
                            double Altura, Comprimento, Largura, Area, Volume;

                            Altura = Double.parseDouble(editTextAltura.getText().toString());
                            Comprimento = Double.parseDouble(editTextComprimento.getText().toString());
                            Largura = Double.parseDouble(editTextLargura.getText().toString());

                            if (Largura >= 3.0 && Altura >= 3.5 && Comprimento >= 3.0){

                                Area = Comprimento * Altura; 
                                Volume = Comprimento * Altura * Largura;

                            if (Area >= 10.5) {
                                 Volume = Double.parseDouble(editTextVolume.getText().toString());
                                    Area = Double.parseDouble(editTextArea.getText().toString());
                                editTextArea.setText(String.format("%1$.2f", Area));
                                 //editTextArea.setText(String.valueOf(Area));
                                editTextVolume.setText(String.format("%1$.2f", Volume));
                                 //editTextVolume.setText(String.valueOf(Volume));
                            } else {
                                alerta.setTitle("Atenção");
                                alerta.setMessage("Área mínima 10.5 metros² !");
                                alerta.setNeutralButton("OK", null);
                                alerta.show();
                                editTextArea.setText("");
                                editTextVolume.setText("");
                                editTextComprimento.setText("");
                                editTextLargura.setText("");
                                editTextAltura.setText("");
                            }
                            }                        
                    }
                        });
                };

        });

    }
}

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutAltura"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/LinearLayoutComprimento" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextFieldAltura"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Altura: " />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/EditTextAltura"
            android:layout_width="180dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutLargura"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/LinearLayoutAltura" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextFieldLargura"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Largura: " />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/EditTextLargura"
            android:layout_width="78dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.99"
            android:ems="10" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutComprimento"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextFieldComprimento"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Comprimento: " />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/EditTextComprimento"
            android:layout_width="118dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.42"
            android:ems="10" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutTecnicos"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/LinearLayoutLargura"
        android:layout_marginTop="115dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextFieldTecnicos"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Qtd. Técnicos: " />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/EditTextTecnicos"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.16"
            android:ems="10"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ButtonTecnicos"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="34dp"
            android:text="Confirmar" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutMainframes"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/LinearLayoutTecnicos"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextFieldMainframes"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Qtd. Mainframes: " />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/EditTextMainframes"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ButtonMainframes"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="34dp"
            android:text="Confirmar" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutCalcular"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/LinearLayoutLargura"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="54dp"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonCalculaAV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="34dp"
            android:minWidth="48dp"
            android:text="Calcular medidas"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextArea"
            android:layout_width="62dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Área" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextVolume"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Volume" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonVerificarMedidas"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/LinearLayoutLargura"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Verificar medidas" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Seria interessante colocar o stacktrace que aparece no logcat, assim daria pra descobrir qual o problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sem testar e olhando bem para seu código, parece que você está delegando `buttonCalculaAV.setOnClickListener()` dentro de `buttonVerificarMedidas.setOnClickListener()`.

Coloque `buttonCalculaAV.setOnClickListener()` fora de `buttonVerificarMedidas.setOnClickListener()`, mas dentro do `OnCreate()`.